# How to do fuzzy live grep on git files?

Tags: neovim, plugin-telescope

I want to be able to do a live fuzzy search on all source-controlled python files for example, or just all source-controlled files. Live, meaning updating in real time. Is there a way to do it?

Initially thought of telescope. It may be quite simple. But I am quite confused from all telescope's terms.
There is https://github.com/davvid/telescope-git-grep.nvim which allow for non-fuzzy search, and there is live grep which allows for fuzzy search if you know how to use it. But it is on all files inside certain directory.

```
require'telescope.builtin'.grep_string{ shorten_path = true, word_match = "-w", only_sort_text = true, search = '' }
```

A simpler question might be:
Is there a way to filter on files when doing live grep that is also generic?
(because getting the right file names is quite simple).

PS.
I did commit and added to ripgrep an option of `filelist` that gets list that contains files https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/pull/2598 . I think it can be done with something like the following code :

```
function! GitF(onlypy)
    let tmp=getcwd()
    :exe ":cd ". expand("%:p:h")
    let top = systemlist("git rev-parse --show-toplevel")[0]
    echo top
    :exe ':cd '. top
    let a=systemlist("git ls-files --full-name" )

    let a = (a:onlypy ? filter(a,{idx,val -> val =~ ".*py$"}): a)
    echo a
    :call writefile(a,'c:\temp\filelist.txt')
    
    "py3 t=[os.path.join(vim.eval("top"),y) for y in vim.eval("a")]
    "echo join(a,' --iglob ')mF
    :exec ":Leaderf rg " . ' --filelist c:\temp\filelist.txt'
    :exe ':cd '.tmp
endfunction
```

However, it still doesn't work for one reason or another. And I do prefer other plugin than leaderf.

Comment: If there is other plugin with that feature, please suggest.

Comment: I understand that you want to fuzzy search a term only within the files under source control and skip the one ignored by source control. Do you confirm my understanding?

Comment: Yes I confirm. It is has to be live, meaning to update in real time as you type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use my branch on both: https://github.com/eyalk11/ripgrep/tree/filelist
and
https://github.com/eyalk11/leaderf/tree/filelist

`filelist` is an option I added to  both `leaderf rg` and `rg` that contains paths that it adds to the paths to consider.

Then use the following function:

```
function! GitF(regfilter)
    let tmp=getcwd()
    :exe ":cd ". expand("%:p:h")
    let top = systemlist("git rev-parse --show-toplevel")[0]
    "echo top
    :exe ':cd '. top
    let a=systemlist("git ls-files --full-name" )
    :if len(a:regfilter)>0
    let a = filter(a,{idx,val -> (val =~ a:regfilter)})
    let a= map(a, {idx,fname -> fnamemodify(fname, ':p')})
    :endif 
    ":echo a
    :call writefile(a,'c:\temp\filelist.txt')
    try
        echohl Question
        let pattern = input("Search pattern: ")
        let pattern = escape(pattern,'"')
    finally
        echohl None
    endtry
    
    :exe ':cd '.tmp
    exec printf("Leaderf rg --filelist c:\\temp\\filelist.txt %s\"%s\"", pattern =~ '^\s*$' ? '' : '-e ', pattern )

endfunction

command! -nargs=1 LfGitExt :call GitF(".*\.". <f-args> ."$" )<CR>
command! -nargs=1 LfGitGen :call GitF(<f-args>)<CR>
```

This function generates the right list of files. Asks you about constant intial input (similar to leaderfinteractive) and does fuzzy search over the files.

To use it , you can use the defined commands

```
:LfGitExt vim
```

(live grep over all vim files in current git proj)

It didn't occur to me(so silly) that ripgrep doesn't do fuzzy search.
In fact, no tool does on recursive search. But leaderf in interactive mode allows to fuzzy search over results obtained by constant search .

That is probably the closest you can get to recursive fuzzy search.

Comment: The result is really good btw.

Comment: ripgrep does not do fuzzy search, but ugrep does, and it is fast too. Perhaps give ugrep a try?

Answer (score 1):

`:Telescope live_grep` is supposed to do that:

- Live search on files
- Filtering out the `.gitignore`

The [telescope-live-grep-args](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope-live-grep-args.nvim) provides:

- Live search on files (bringing result while searching)
- Passing arguments to the underlying `rg` and in particular the `-g` and `-g!` argument that allow filtering against file patterns.

For searching for file content I personally use the [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) plugin that provides:

- Live search on files (bringing result while searching)
- Restricting on some file type

e.g.:

```
:CtrlSF -T py foo
```

Search for foo in all the Python files.

Comment: While it may ignores the `.gitignore`,  doesn't it include all files that are not in git ignore, even if they are not in source control.

Comment: I initially forgot that I wanted to filter on file names (/extension).

Comment: You are right the solution is not perfect. But since `git add .` will add them it is probably wise to make sure `.gitignore` is adapted such they are ignored ;-)

Comment: This plugin is cute. Almost does what I wanted. Even though I defined the backend to be rg, it seems to do exact search.

Comment: I have made a command that uses Leaderfrg with --iglob for every python file in the project. But it is awful, and fails when there are too many files. RG simply doesn't support it.

Comment: A bit out of scope. But I didn't succeed in making telescope work with rg. So could you say a few words about it?

Comment: I believe you have to set `grepprg` to `rg` more precisely: `set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep`

Comment: I'm not sure if my last comment address your last demand. Is your demand related to [telescope-live-grep-args](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope-live-grep-args.nvim) usage?

Comment: Yes, how to use rg in telescope live grep args. I am quite OK with my solution but curious to know what I have missed.

Comment: Did you tried what I have suggested? It works for me.

Comment: I tried CtrlSF. It is quite nice. Still not related to git. I liked the grepprg but I am not going to use it probably.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) good to know you have found a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is `require("telescope.builtin").git_files()` which does what you want.

There is also `require("telescope.builtin").find_files()` and with `require("telescope.builtin").find_files { hidden = true, no_ignore = true }` you can search for hidden files

The grep things in Telescope are for searching words in files, not files itself

Comment: It doesn't. Live grep meaning grep inside files, not grep on file names. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: I'm just curious if you really need to find files with grep, fuzzy find feels so much more suitable for this

Comment: I want fuzzy search inside files. I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: I think you are confusing things and confusing me.
Fuzzy - when you input some text and search for this text no matter where it's in line and which order. You asking how to fuzzy live grep which doesn't even make sense. You either use regex or fuzzy search, not both

Comment: Fuzzy means to match even if it is not exact match "dscription" matches lines with description.. it can be formulated in terms of Levinstein distance.

Comment: still not regex